# Android How to prevent Drawable resizing to fill container

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have a drawable (just a red circle)

```
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:height="12dp" />
        <size android:width="12dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorNonCompliant" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I want to use it in a MaterialCalendarView, as a background on the calendar for a single day. The code for it is

```
class CurrentDayDecorator(context: Activity?, currentDay: CalendarDay) : DayViewDecorator {
    private val drawable: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.ic_circle_noncompliant_calendar)
    var myDay = currentDay
    override fun shouldDecorate(day: CalendarDay): Boolean {
        return day == myDay
    }

    override fun decorate(view: DayViewFacade) {
        view.setSelectionDrawable(drawable!!)
    }

    init {
        // You can set background for Decorator via drawable here
    }
}
```

But the circle gets resized to fully fit the box/container for that certain day. I want the circle to be smaller, how can I size it accordingly? I tried padding but failed. Thanks in advance

Comment: So this isnt an exact solution but my solution was to have 2 circles on top of each other, the bigger one under the actual circle was the color of the background so it acted as if it didnt exist. I used android:bottom="13dp"
        android:left="13dp"
        android:right="13dp"
        android:top="13dp to make the actual circle smaller in the item descroption